# Slow Query logging everything

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance, query, slow-log

I have a mysql instance that is logging slow queries. I have it set to 1 sec, but I am getting back lots of these:(example)
   Query_time: 0.000237  Lock_time: 0.000064 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 109

On another server I get these:
   Query_time: 0  Lock_time: 0  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0

Either way they both seem to be logging other queries...or am I reading something wrong?

```
set-variable = log-slow-queries="/tmp/mysql-slow-query.log"
   set-variable = long_query_time=1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using mysql 5.1.21 or newer, you can change the behavior of logging slow queries with the [min_examined_row_length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_min-examined-row-limit)

Set it to something like 5000 or so, and keep your log_queries_not_using_indexes turned on.

Comment: that's a +1 for an interesting approach I never explored before.

Comment: @derekdowney  Do you mean  min_examined_row_limit  ?  If so, please correct.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should raise the [**long_query_time**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time) to 10 (the default value)

MySQL 5.1 allows sub-second granularity of the long_query_time, which may explain why you see decmial notation for the first slow query log display.

You may also want to check and make sure that [**log_queries_not_using_indexes**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-queries-not-using-indexes) is not enabled. Otherwise, any old query not using indexes will bypass the long_query_time setting and get recorded in the slow log.

CAVEAT

[**set-variable is deprecated in MySQL 5.1**](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MySQL/Q_26171801.html)

This is from MySQL 5.1.37

```
  -O, --set-variable=name
                      Change the value of a variable. Please note that this
                      option is deprecated;you can set variables directly with
                      --variable-name=value.
```